# Checking MySQL Query value for '%' character with Regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I want to check if a value for a MySQL Query contain `%` character (can appear multiple times) but not the escaped `\%`.

So it should match:

- `'%test'`
- `'%test\%'`
- `'test\\%'` - should match because it's escape the `\` not the `%`
- `'%test\%%'`
- `'\%test%test\%'`

but not:

- `'test\%'`
- `'\%test\%'`
- `'\%test\%test\%'`

I'm not good in Regular Expression, can someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
I'm trying creating a PHP Library for generating SQL Query from an array, and maybe the generated query will be used mostly on MySQL.
So, the regex filtering process will be in PHP.

Sorry, I forgot to mention this.

Thanks

Comment: what rdbms? sqlserver? mysql? oracle?...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this on PHP code:

```
unset($str1,$str2,$str3,$str4,$str5,$str6,$str7);

$str1 = '%100'; 
$str2 = '%100\%';
$str3 = "100\\\\%";
$str4 = "%100\\%%";
$str5 = '100\%';
$str6 = "100\\\\\\\\%";
$str7 = "100\\\\\\%";
$str8 = "100\\\\\\\\\\\\%";
$str9 = "100\\\\\\\\\\\\\\%";

$reg_exp=  '/^%|[^\x5C]%|[^\x5C](\x5C\x5C)+%/';

echo $str1.' = '.preg_match($reg_exp, $str1).'<br />';
echo $str2.' = '.preg_match($reg_exp, $str2).'<br />';
echo $str3.' = '.preg_match($reg_exp, $str3).'<br />';
echo $str4.' = '.preg_match($reg_exp, $str4).'<br />';
echo $str5.' = '.preg_match($reg_exp, $str5).'<br />';
echo $str6.' = '.preg_match($reg_exp, $str6).'<br />';
echo $str7.' = '.preg_match($reg_exp, $str7).'<br />';
echo $str8.' = '.preg_match($reg_exp, $str8).'<br />';
echo $str9.' = '.preg_match($reg_exp, $str9).'<br />';
```

http://ideone.com/Bgq5bV

Comment: The third statement return 0. But 1 expected

Comment: I have edit the reg_exp. Let me check the answer (I think this doesn't work with many consecutive \\)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server, this *should* work:

```
WHERE
  ColumnX LIKE '%[%]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Though I'm not sure if it handles `\\%` correctly.

This should work in any case:

```
WHERE
  REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnX, '\\', ''), '\%', '') LIKE '%[%]%'
```